Sanitizing PATH in case of duplicates
I have set
typeset -aU path

which helps in avoiding duplicates in my PATH. The duplicate is not added if I add it at the end to my PATH:
path+=~/bin
path+=~/foo
path+=~/bin

After this, my PATH contains only one copy of my bin directory.
If I put a directory at the start of the PATH (which is rarely done, but sometimes necessary), i.e.
PATH=~/bin:$PATH

I will end up with an additional copy of my bin directory in my PATH. Is it possible to also automatically remove duplicate directories in this case?
I can force this manually with the help of an auxiliary array, i.e.
temppath=($path)
path=($temppath)

but I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this.

It looks like the -U (unique) attribute can be set separately for each variable in a pair of tied parameters like path and PATH. The two names essentially act as distinct interfaces to a shared bit of data, and the behavior changes when different interfaces are used to set and retrieve that data.
By setting -U for both path and PATH, the shell should remove duplicates no matter how entries are added:
typeset -U PATH path

This is all that's absolutely necessary, since by default the -T (tied) and -a (array) attributes for path/PATH are already set. For a new variable that behaves similarly, the declaration could look like this:
typeset -aUT LD_LIBRARY_PATH ld_library_path

Testing:
=> typeset -aUT PATH path
=> PATH=/usr/bin
=> path+=~/bin
=> typeset -p path
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /usr/bin /Users/me/bin )
=> path+=~/foo
=> path+=~/bin
=> typeset -p path
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /usr/bin /Users/me/bin /Users/me/foo )
=> PATH=~/bin:$PATH
=> typeset -p path
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /Users/me/bin /usr/bin /Users/me/foo )
=> path=(~/foo $path)
=> typeset -p path
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /Users/me/foo /Users/me/bin /usr/bin )

With -U set differently for PATH and path:
=> path=()
=> typeset -U path; typeset +U PATH
=> typeset -p PATH path
typeset -T PATH path=(  )
typeset -aUT PATH path=(  )
=> PATH=/foo:/foo:/foo
=> typeset -p PATH path
typeset -T PATH path=( /foo /foo /foo )
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /foo /foo /foo )
=> path+=/bar; path+=/bar; path+=/bar
=> typeset -p PATH path
typeset -T PATH path=( /foo /bar )
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /foo /bar )
=> PATH=/foo:$PATH; PATH=/foo:$PATH;
=> typeset -p PATH path
typeset -T PATH path=( /foo /foo /foo /bar )
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /foo /foo /foo /bar )

=> path=()
=> typeset +U path; typeset -U PATH
=> typeset -p PATH path
typeset -UT PATH path=(  )
typeset -aT PATH path=(  )
=> path+=/alice; path+=/alice; path+=/alice
=> typeset -p PATH path
typeset -UT PATH path=( /alice /alice /alice )
typeset -aT PATH path=( /alice /alice /alice )
=> PATH=$PATH:/bob; PATH=$PATH:/bob; PATH=$PATH:/bob; 
=> typeset -p PATH path
typeset -UT PATH path=( /alice /bob )
typeset -aT PATH path=( /alice /bob )


Bonus - path=($^path(-/N)) can be used to remove non-existent directories and empty and invalid entries from path:
=> typeset -p path   
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /Users/me/foo /Users/me/bin /etc/hosts '' /usr/bin )
=> path=($^path(-/N))
=> typeset -p path   
typeset -aUT PATH path=( /Users/me/bin /usr/bin )


${^...} - emulate brace expansion. Each element in the array is expanded with the surrounding text, e.g.:  /Users/me/foo(/N) /Users/me/bin(/N) /etc/hosts(/N) /usr/bin(/N).
(-/) - only include directories and symbolic links to directories in the glob expansions.
(N) - allow empty glob results.
So:

/Users/me/foo(-/N) expands to nothing / null since it does not exist.
/Users/me/bin(-/N) becomes /Users/me/bin.
/etc/hosts(-/N) is null because it's a file.
''(-/N) is null because it's empty. If it had remained in the path it would have been the same as ., i.e. the current directory. That can create a security issue.
/usr/bin(-/N) becomes /usr/bin.


path=(...) - resets path to whatever remains from the expansion. If -U is set for path, then only unique values are added.

Another version: path=( ${(M)^path:#/*}(N-/) ), from @Stephane Chazelas in the comments.  This will eliminate all relative entries from the path, not just empty values (which are interpreted as .). This is useful because those entries are also a security risk.
MacOS sometimes adds pointless entries via /etc/paths.d, this is a way to clean them out.

path and PATH are tied variables. What you do to the one, you can do to the other. I just use the spelling depending on what I find more convenient to type.  Setting -U  for both variables does not do any danger, but has no effect. However, your idea of getting rid of the temporary array is cool. I didn't think of it. Could you also explain the syntax behind $^~path? The ~ would do tilde expansion inside the PATH variable (IMO unnecessary), but how does the ^  work? I guess this is responsible for removing duplicates.

The -U option can be set separately for PATH and path - I added some examples to the answer, along with other notes. We probably don't need ~ in the path=($^~path(/N)) expansion, but I haven't tested out every scenario.

I don't think this is correct. I have set -U only on path, and when I update path on the right (end of the array), it is made unique, and this is reflected in PATH, and vice versa. Using zsh 5.8.1

What happens when you update it using PATH instead of path, and what do typeset -p PATH and typeset -p path show? The zsh documentation for -U refers to PATH and path as distinct interfaces, which may be a better way of thinking of them.    The tests above were run with zsh 5.9.

Indeed! I checked, and could verify it for my zsh as well.

Yes, sorry, my bad, I actually had typeset -U path in my ~/.zshrc, which explained why I only needed typeset -U PATH.
